# Gradle sync failed: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'aFileName' of com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName must not be null

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I imported my project to `Android Studio 1.3.2` and now it is showing error

```
Gradle sync started
Gradle sync failed: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'aFileName' of com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName must not be null
Gradle sync completed
IllegalArgumentException: Failed to set up Android modules in project 'MaterialTabs': Argument for @NotNull parameter 'aFileName' of com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName must not be null
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.abcd"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.24.3.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue,i just did invalidate cache and restart it, it worked.

but still if there is issue i suggest try to change compileSdkVersion from gradle