# Android Studio 3.2.1 - Cannot sync project with gradle files: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of ... must not be null

Tags: linux, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.2

I have a problem using AndroidStudio. I freshly installed it on my Kubuntu 18.04 machine and wanted to create my frist project. Everyhting worked fine and the project opened. The only problem: I can't run my apps. I can't even look at the activities in the design view - It waits forever for the build to finish. When I want to run the apps, it doesn't have any modules.

After searching for a while on the web I tried syncing my project with the gradle files, because that seems to resolve similar issues, but once I do that, the following error occurs:

```
Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/GradleSyncState.syncFailed must not be null
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/GradleSyncState.syncFailed must not be null
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.$$$reportNull$$$0(GradleSyncState.java)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.syncFailed(GradleSyncState.java)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.doPopulateProject(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:135)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populate(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:97)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.access$000(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:39)
        at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask$1.run(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:86)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

After doing it once, the button for syncing is disabled and I can't do it again. I have to restart the IDE to do that.

I looked into the idea.log file to better track down the issue and I found the following there:

```
2018-10-22 22:38:32,254 [d thread 3]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.version=3.2 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.2.1.0 -Pandroid.builder.sdkDownload=false --init-script /tmp/ijinit.gradle --offline 
2018-10-22 22:38:43,063 [d thread 3]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started setup of project 'TestApp'. 
2018-10-22 22:38:43,065 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SETUP_STARTED 
2018-10-22 22:38:43,263 [e-1136-b06]   INFO - ule.android.SdkModuleSetupStep - Set Android SDK 'Android API 28 Platform (1)' (/home/myusername/Android/Sdk) to module 'app' 
2018-10-22 22:38:43,567 [d thread 3]   WARN - ea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask - Sync failed: null 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator.invokeAndWait(LaterInvocator.java:179)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:651)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:656)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeOnEdt(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:480)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.executeProjectChangeAction(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:469)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.dispose(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:442)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:221)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:228)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.doPopulateProject(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:120)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populate(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.access$000(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:39)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask$1.run(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.disposeArea(Extensions.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleImpl.dispose(ModuleImpl.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer$1.execute(Disposer.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer$1.execute(Disposer.java:44)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeActionWithRecursiveGuard(ObjectTree.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeUnregistered(ObjectTree.java:181)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.objectTree.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:140)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:125)
    at com.intellij.openapi.module.impl.ModuleManagerImpl$ModuleModelImpl.dispose(ModuleManagerImpl.java:895)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.dispose(AbstractIdeModifiableModelsProvider.java:476)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl$3.execute(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:445)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.DisposeAwareProjectChange.run(DisposeAwareProjectChange.java:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1010)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemApiUtil.lambda$executeProjectChangeAction$6(ExternalSystemApiUtil.java:469)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.doRun(LaterInvocator.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:431)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:415)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:763)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2018-10-22 22:38:43,570 [e-1136-b06]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/GradleSyncState.syncFailed must not be null 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'message' of com/android/tools/idea/gradle/project/sync/GradleSyncState.syncFailed must not be null
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.$$$reportNull$$$0(GradleSyncState.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.GradleSyncState.syncFailed(GradleSyncState.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.doPopulateProject(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:135)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populate(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.access$000(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:39)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask$1.run(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:750)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-10-22 22:38:43,572 [e-1136-b06]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Android Studio 3.2.1  Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338 
2018-10-22 22:38:43,572 [e-1136-b06]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - JDK: 1.8.0_152-release 
2018-10-22 22:38:43,572 [e-1136-b06]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2018-10-22 22:38:43,572 [e-1136-b06]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2018-10-22 22:38:43,572 [e-1136-b06]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - OS: Linux 
2018-10-22 22:38:43,572 [e-1136-b06]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Last Action: Android.SyncProject
```

It seems like the project can't be synced to my gradle files. Probably the actual problem of running my app is based upon this one. Has anyone had this issue before or can help me by telling me how to tackle this?

I am completely new to AndroidStudio and also to Gradle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle sync failed: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'aFileName' of com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtil.toSystemIndependentName must not be null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36762820/608639)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, I was finally able to figure out the reason.

The problem was, that my project folder resided on a different hard disk partition, than my home folder. The folder containing my android projects was linked to my home folder with a symbolic link.

I can't tell whether its the symbolic link, or the other partition, that is causing the problem. I haven't checked that. Maybe it works if you have it on the same partition but linked with a symbolic link. Maybe it works when used on another partition without symbolic links. But for anyone experiencing this problem -> Check if one of these might be your cause as well.

Some extra information: My android project folder resided on a hard disk partition formatted with ZFS.

Comment: Definitely `symbolic links`... I hit the same problem, and had mine setup using symbolic links within the same partition (`ext4`)

Comment: That was the problem in my case. The solution was to import the project from the real path, without sym link.
Other projects work with symlink, don't know why this one doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I also faced this due to symbolic link from different partition.

Comment: Thumbs are up! that is the solution

Comment: Saved my life... spent hours banging my head on this

Answer (score 8):

I saw a version of this with just now on Android Studio 3.4: the only error message I saw in the IDE was that Gradle sync failed, but in `idea.log` there was a `NullPointerException` and its traceback originated at `com.intellij.openapi.extensions.Extensions.disposeArea` and was just like the one in the question.

The fix that **worked for me:**

1. `rm .idea/modules.xml`
2. Then try Gradle sync again.

This also caused that file to get automatically regenerated.  The new version had exactly the same entries as the old, plus some additional ones for various library dependencies.  Not sure if those entries being absent was the cause of the issue, or an unrelated accident.

Before that, I tried "Invalidate Caches / Restart...", and it didn't work in my case.  Also double-checked and there are no symbolic links in my project path, or the paths to Android Studio or the Android SDK.

Comment: I am getting `.idea/modules.xml: No such file or directory` when I run `rm .idea/modules.xml `.
`

Comment: If there's no `.idea/modules.xml`, then this fix probably won't be the one for you. There seem to be a number of different things that can cause these symptoms, and different things to do to fix them. Definitely look through all the answers here, and if one doesn't work then try another.

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar problem after renaming the project folder and adding the renamed folder as new project.

- solved this by the infamous "Invalidate Caches / Restart" option

*(before I removed the old project link which was not enough)*

Comment: This error appeared after moving the project into different folder, `Android Studio > File > Invalidate Cache / Restart` helped to solve it.

Comment: a great option :D

Answer (score 2):

check this :
[Argument for @NotNull parameter 'module' of com/intellij/openapi/roots/ModuleRootManager.getInstance must not be null](https://github.com/raniejade/spek-idea-plugin/issues/30#issuecomment-365185006)

by the way , i usually delete `.idea` and `.gradle` folders inside my project folder after updating android studio , almost works for all new bugs after updating .

Comment: Thank you @AliReza for your answer. I was able to figure out the problem in a different way. :)

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue, wasted a day reinstalling everything and figured out just now. It happens if you create a symbolic link to your project and specify the path through that symbolic link. Just specify the project path by going the long way and everything will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I move the ~/Android/Sdk folder to a different partition and placed a symbolic link!!!

Solution for me:
Delete .android , .AndroidStudio3.2 , .gradle folders
Start studio.sh again and let it initialize things as for the first time. Then go to File->settings->System Settings->Android SDK and give the new location to the Android SDK folder as an absolute path (not symbolic links).

After this, it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by rename the project folder and then reopen android studio , android studio will tell you that it  can not find the project , then remove the project from the android studio current open list . rename project folder back and open it by android studio again .

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue in Android Studio 3.4.
I managed to fix it by restoring my previously deleted app-name.iml file.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem and simply resolved it by closing android studio, deleting .idea and .gradle files located on the project folder and then reopening android studio.

Comment: Incase this fails, you can try the  "Invalidate Caches / Restart" option